# Angular 2 - Getting empty array when trying to map from json

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, subscription

My issue is that in my subscribeEquippedItems(): Observable method after mapping to an array of type Item for some reason the output is an empty array instead of a array.

So just to test that I was getting objects back I did the following in the constructor of my class:

```
this.subscribeTest()
    .subscribe(items => { console.log('TEST: '); console.log(items); });
```

Which calls the following method in that class:

```
subscribeTest(): Observable<any> {
    return this.af.database.list('users/uniqueIdIsHere/equippedItems');
}
```

This output an array of 3 objects in the console.
They are like this:

```
[Object, Object, Object]
```

When opened they look like:

```
Array[3]
    0: Object
        title: "testtitle"
        active: false
    1: Object
    2: Object
```

In my class that will display the items I have:

```
loadItems() {
    this.itemsService.subscribeEquippedItems().subscribe(x => {
        // this.equippedItems = x;
        console.log(x);
    });
}
```

Which calls the itemsService:

```
subscribeEquippedItems(): Observable<Item[]> {
    let yoyo = Observable.of(new Array<Item>());

    this.session.uid.subscribe(x => {
        console.log('users/' + x + '/equippedItems'); // this is correct vaue
        yoyo = this.af.database.list('users/' + x + '/equippedItems')
            .map(Item.fromJsonList).do(z => {
                console.log('trying to map here');
                console.log(z);
            }).do(s => {
                console.log('STARTSTARTSTARTSTART: ');
                console.log(s); // this shows as an empty array in console
                console.log(' : FINISHFINISHFINISH');
            });
    });
    return yoyo;
}
```

Here is the item class:

```
public title: string;
public active: boolean;

static fromJsonList(array: any): Item[] {
    console.log('tester');
    console.log(array); // blank array shows on console
    return array.map(Item.fromJson);
}

static fromJson({title, active}: any): Item {
  return new AvatarItem(title,active);
}

constructor(title: string, active: boolean){
    this.title = title;
    this.active = active;
}
```

Comment: add `return z;` after  `console.log('trying to map here');  console.log(z);`

Comment: what you are trying to do here `.map(Item.fromJsonList).`, do you need  static methods?